# Expandable List View, with loop

Tags: java, android, list, for-loop, expandablelistview

Is there any way to create an Expandable Listview on Android, from 4 separate Lists?

For example I have:

```
String [] titles = "Bob", "Anna", "Georgia";
String [] phones = "123456678", "2310521010" , "98745632123";
String [] sites  = "www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.etc.com";
String [] address = "Here", "there", "away";
```

And I'm wanting the parent of Expandable Listview to be the titles[1], and the children:phones[1], sites[1] and etc.
I tried and I putted the names with this:

```
names = Arrays.asList(titles);
```

But I cannot add the children.What I want to do is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
inMyExpandableView.put(phones(i),sites(i),address(i));
```

Is it possible?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a recycler view instead of a list view.

Procedure as follows :

1. Inflate the recycler view with the Parent elements.
2. OnClick of each item in the parent, add the related children in the recycler view adapter.
3. Call notifyDataSetChanged API or an equivalent API in the adapter.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial/library](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/) for doing an expandable recycler view with parent/child items. I've implemented it and it works really well.